# Show Values of single rows into multiple columns

Tags: sql

I need to create sql that will list pairs who have the same plant

There are 3 tables

```
Plant_Table
--------------
Snum     Plant    cost
  A      Rose      5.00
  B      Willow    6.00
  C      Lilly     7.00

Landscaper_Table
----------------
Lnum    Lname           Laddress
  1      Dr Plant         xxx st
  2      Plant Scaper     zzz st 
  3      George Gardener  yyy st

land_plant_Table
---------------
Lnum    Snum    instock
  1      A         3
  2      A         3
  2      B         3
  2      C         3
  3      A         3
  3      C         3
```

I need to list pairs of contractors, and the name of the supplies for contractors who keep the same supplies in stock

An example of results I want would be

```
Landscaper1    Landscaper2       Landscaper 3          Plant
  Dr plant      George Gardener     Plant Scaper           Rose
  Plant Scaper  George Gardener      ---                  Lilly
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Please describe the schema properly.

Comment: Show an example as to what is the result you want

Comment: an example of the results I want would be 
Contractor1 Contractor2 Supplies
Cname          Cname     Supply name

where the 2 contractor names are different

Comment: sorry, i dont know how to format properly on here yet..

Comment: Can you give some *sample* data and *expected* results. Please *edit* your question (edit link is bottom left, below the tags) because you'll probably want to format such data using the `{}` button so that you can show us a table, which is impossible to do in the comments.

Comment: ok i will change the data to hopefully make it more understandable, thankyou

Comment: does that make any more sense?

Comment: @user3436223 : you want the ouput in 4 columns???whats wrong with 2 column output?

Comment: im trying your answer now to see if it would be ok, is there any way to do it without manually entering the plants?

Comment: you can pass it through the scripting language u r using..`php` may be! :)

Comment: is it `mysql` or some other `sql`??

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not mentioned the database, I've solved it using sql server.

```
select plant,
max(case when row='1' then name end) L1,
max(case when row='2' then name end) L2,
max(case when row='3' then name end) L3
from 
(
select lt.lname as name, pt.plant as plant, 
  row_number() over(partition by pt.plant order by pt.plant) as row
from plant_table pt 
inner join land_plant_Table lpt on lpt. snum = pt.snum 
inner join Landscaper_Table lt on lpt.lnum = lt.lnum
) as s
group by plant
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ceeaa/33)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, its not possible to show in pairs...a single file printing in two columns is suggeted by below answer

Simply join `land_plant_Table` with  `Plant_Table` and `Landscaper_Table` based on `Lnum` and `Lnum` and filter out using supplies in `where` clause.

Something like this would do ( *based on your last table schema before update!* )

**via joins**

```
select lt.lname, pt.plant
from plant_table pt 
inner join land_plant_Table lpt on lpt. snum = ct.snum 
inner join Landscaper_Table lt on lpt.lnum = lt.lnum
where pt.plant='rose' /* or pt.plant IN ('rose','willow','blah','blah','blah' )*/
```

**via subquery :**

1st fetch the the `snum` -> then based on snum, fetch `lnum` -> based on lnum, fetch `lname`

```
select lname from Landscaper_table where lnum in ( 
    select lnum from land_plant_table where lnum in (
           select snum from plant_table where plant IN ('rose','willow','blah','blah','blah' )
)
```